# GroupieViewHolder shown error when i declared it

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, groupie

im new to kotlin android development and trying to build a messenger follow the youtube tutorial by lets build that apps (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuRiwVF5bzs&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JE-jiBHjxlmXEkQkum_M3R-&index=4  >from 19:33) i founded i the GroupieViewHolder is not working, i spent 4 hour of time but still not able to find the arror.\

Below is what i have tried.

This is my project level gradle.file
`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false

}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my app level gradle.file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdk 32

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.assignment"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }


}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    //Progress dialog library
    implementation 'com.jpardogo.googleprogressbar:library:1.2.0'

    //TODO https://github.com/lisawray/groupie  cannnot add groupie into gradle.
    //implementation "com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie:$groupie_version"
    implementation "com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie:2.10.0"
    implementation 'com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.10.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

This is settings:gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }  
       jcenter() 
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Assignment"
include ':app'
```

This is the activity file (NewMessageActivity.kt)

```
package com.example.assignment

import android.content.ClipData
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.renderscript.Sampler
import android.util.Log
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.xwray.groupie.GroupieAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_new_message.*

import com.xwray.groupie.kotlinandroidextensions.Item
import com.xwray.groupie.kotlinandroidextensions.GroupieViewHolder
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.song.*  //THIS CANNOT BE IMPORTED
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.my_item_layout.* //THIS CANNOT BE IMPORTED
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.user_row_new_message.view.*

class NewMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_message)

        supportActionBar?.title="Select User"

        fetchUsers()
    }

    private fun fetchUsers() {
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Users")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val adapter = GroupieAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>() //HERE IS THE ERROR

                p0.children.forEach {
                    Log.d("NewMessage", it.toString())
                    val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
                    if(user != null) {
                        adapter.add(UserItem(user))
                    }

                }
                recyclerview_newmessage.adapter=adapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
    }
}
class UserItem(val user: User): Item<GroupieViewHolder>() { //HERE IS THE ERROR
    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.itemView.username_textview_new_message.text = user.username
        Picasso.get().load(user.profileImageUrl).into(viewHolder.itemView.imageview_new_message)
    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.user_row_new_message
    }
}
```

Below is the error shown when i mouse hover to GroupieViewHolder

[image: Here is the error when my mouse hover to GroupieViewHolder]

Comment: I edited your question as it seems more of a semantic issue than a Firebase one. The issue is about [generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html), the GroupieAdapter doesn't have any generic parameter on it that's why your'e getting that compile error

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps,

1. **kotlin-android-extension** is Deprecated. use **ViewBinding** or **DataBinding** inorder to work properly.

   ```
   //remove deprecated 
    implementation 'com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.10.0'

   //for viewbinding ,replace with
   implementation "com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie-viewbinding:2.10.0"
   ```
2. update **Groupie Librar**y to **latest version(2.10.1)** which added support for kotlin version 1.6 ([check more about here.](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie/releases/tag/2.10.1)).

Once you added, it will like below.
[image]

3. Enable **ViewBinding** or **Databinding** in **App Level Gradle** File inside android tag.

> viewBinding{    enabled = true }

[image]

4. if you not aware on **viewBinding**, please learn that (which is pretty simple to understand.)
5. now you have to change the **UserItem** into below in **NewMessageActivity.kt**,

   ```
   //item with viewBinding.
    class UserItem(val user: User): BindableItem<UserRowNewMessageBinding>() {

    // Other implementations...
    override fun bind(viewBinding: UserRowNewMessageBinding, position: Int) {
        viewBinding.usernameTextviewNewMessage.text = user.username
        Picasso.get()
               .load(user.profileImageUrl)
               .into(viewBinding.imageviewNewMessage)
    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int = R.layout.user_row_new_message

    override fun initializeViewBinding(view: View): UserRowNewMessageBinding {
        return UserRowNewMessageBinding.bind(view)
    }
    }
   ```

- **UserRowNewMessageBinding** - Your item layout binding id.
- viewBinding.**usernameTextviewNewMessage** - Your item TextView binding id.
- viewBinding.**imageviewNewMessage** - Your item ImageView binding id.

6. Change the initialization of **GroupieAdapter** inside **fetchUser()** in **newMessageActivity.kt**.  like below

   ```
   val adapter = GroupieAdapter() //remove the Generic Type here. which is no longer need.
   ```

DON'T FORGET TO **SYNC,REBUILD** ONCE YOU CHANGE ANYTHING IN **GRADLE** FILES.

**TIP**,
If you are new to **Android Development**, always get learn from some latest version of videos,blogs or atleast less 2 years old videos/blogs.